# MediaElement.js HTML5 video player pre-rolls not working when frequency capping enabled in DFP

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement.js, google-dfp

We're currently using the [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) HTML5 video player for site viewing on tablets and are using [DFP](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/) to serve pre-rolls via VAST. The main parts of this works fine (playback, tracking of views and clicks), but we are encountering an issue where pre-rolls will not serve at all when frequency capping (i.e., max once per 5 minutes for each line item) is enabled for them in DFP. This does not appear to be specific to playback in tablet browsers (e.g., based on default cookie security settings), as testing in desktop browsers returns the same results. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue, and if so, what was done to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this by not pulling the DFP XML file directly, but by using the [Google IMA HTML5 library](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/) to do so. As soon as we did this, frequency capping no longer became an issue.